# Edit an image in java

Tags: java, image, methods, jframe

I have an image a map, The image must be contained in a JFrame and asked whether there are any java method that given coordinates (x, y) must make a kind of water mark or repaint the picture only in the specified coordinate

anyone knows how to do or any idea how it would try to do ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new SubClass of [ImageIcon](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) and ovveride the method paintIcon. E.g.:

```
    class MyImageIcon extends ImageIcon
    {
    public MyImageIcon(Image img)
      {
      super(img);
      }
   public  void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y)
     {
     super.paintIcon(c,g,x,y);
     g.drawLine(0,0,10,10);// .... paint your mark here
     }
    };
```

then put this MyImageIcon in a JLabel.

Hope it helps
Pierre